# SSRS - what is the lifecycle of a dataset

Tags: reporting-services, dataset

I'm developing an SSRS report comprising several sub-report. One of them is only used as wrapper for another sub-report representing some data. The wrapper report is having a query and it checks whether the returned dataset is empty or not. If empty, the sub-report (the one showing the data) is hidden and a label is shown. Otherwise the label is hidden but the subreport with the data is shown.
The wrapping report and the sub-report have identical datasets with same parameter values.

My question is: is the database query specified by the dataset executed twice or only once (especially in the case when data is returned and the sub-report has to be shown)?

If executed twice, is there a recomended way to handle the scenario so the performance is improved?

Comment: This is not the best answer which is why I'm making this a comment. When an SSRS report is rendered every time the dataset is checked it calls the data provider's GetData() method. If you write your own custom data provider to return datasets for your reports. In that method you could write logic to not query the underlying data source if a condition exists.